# squid.confの設定が上手く機能していない？

Tags: linux, vmware, squid

会社用のPCでVMware Player上にPhoton OSをインストール。squid proxyとして動作させる意図。

追加した点は、

```
# 許可するIPアドレスを追加(自分のPCのアドレス)
#acl allowed_clients_1 src 192.168.11.11　(会社のPC)
acl allowed_clients_2 src 192.168.11.13  (自分のPC)

# *アドレスは変えています
# 下記追加 allowed_clientsは192.168.110.110,192.168.110.130を許可する
http_access allow allowed_clients_1
http_access allow allowed_clients_2
http_access deny all
```

・googleのプロキシ設定から画像

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 解決したい問題

自分のPCからChromeで適当なサイトにアクセスしようとするとアクセス許可が上手く設定されていないのかアクセスできない状態です。
squid.confのファイル設定で不備がありますでしょうか？

下記squid.conf中身

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
#acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255 # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8            # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10         # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
#acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16        # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
#acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16                # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
#acl localnet src fc00::/7              # RFC 4193 local private network range
#acl localnet src fe80::/10             # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http


#許可するIPアドレスを追加(自分のPCのアドレス)
#acl allowed_clients_1 src 192.168.11.11
acl allowed_clients_2 src 192.168.11.13

# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#ここにhttp_accessエントリを含むリストを入れる。
#下記追加 allowed_clientsは192.168.11.11,192.168.11.13を許可する
http_access allow allowed_clients_1
http_access allow allowed_clients_2
http_access deny all




#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# This default configuration only allows localhost requests because a more
# permissive Squid installation could introduce new attack vectors into the
# network by proxying external TCP connections to unprotected services.
http_access allow localhost

# The two deny rules below are unnecessary in this default configuration
# because they are followed by a "deny all" rule. However, they may become
# critically important when you start allowing external requests below them.

# Protect web applications running on the same server as Squid. They often
# assume that only local users can access them at "localhost" ports.
http_access deny to_localhost

# Protect cloud servers that provide local users with sensitive info about
# their server via certain well-known link-local (a.k.a. APIPA) addresses.
http_access deny to_linklocal


# For example, to allow access from your local networks, you may uncomment the
# following rule (and/or add rules that match your definition of "local"):
# http_access allow localnet

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320


#ログフォーマット追加
logformat timefm %{%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}tl %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %[un %Sh/%<a %mt
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log timefm
```